# 2d Projection of a 3d Object

Tags: opengl, 3d, rendering, projection, vtk

I have found some solution but they are more complex algorithms than what i need.
my problem, I have a 3d object that is represented by points and cells in 3d space and I want to take a picture of 3d object one side(it will be perpendicular one axis like xz,xy and yz) without rendering(a algorithms I will wrote) because I need points and cells for drawing & scaling in other painter(not 3d). Thus, I don't need perspective just taking picture of 3d object from one side(back front up down etc..) then I want to obtain cells and points of that projection.
is there any solution for this problem

Comment: If you only want the (orthographic) projection onto the XY plane (or any other plane), just don't use the coordinates along the axis perpendicular to the plane (in this case, the Z coordinates). Vertex (1, 3, 1) will simply project to (1, 3) in 2D.

Comment: I know it but here problem is how can I determine which line polys points visible on that plane?

Comment: Sorry, I understood that you would be implementing painter's algorithm for depth sorting. Now I'm not sure what you're asking.